# Omitting extension with find?

Tags: find, imagemagick

I need to create thumbnails from multiple .png files and would like to do this using ImageMagicks `convert` utility. To recursively find all files that are not thumbnails themselves, I am using the following call (split into two lines to make it readable):

```
find . -type f -name "*.png" -not -name "*thumb.png*" \
  -exec convert {} -thumbnail 200x200 {}.thumb.png \;`
```

But this would of course create a file named `a.png.thumb.png` when running it on a file called `a.png`. How could I remove the `.png` extension from the second `{}` parameter passed to convert?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to pass the `{}` off to a shell like `sh` and have the shell do it:

```
find ... \
    -exec sh -c 'convert "$0" -thumbnail 200x200 "${0%.png}.thumb.png"' {} \;
```