# Howto recursively create PDF thumnbails on Linux command line

Tags: command-line, find, xargs, imagemagick

I am able to use ImageMagick to create a thumbnail of the first page of a PDF using:

```
convert -thumbnail x80 95.pdf[0] thumb_95.png
```

This works fine and generates a **thumb_95.png** file.

I have tried several permutations of "find" using xargs but I can't get a combo working that will create the thumbnails in the folders along with the source PDFs.

The PDFs are in folders named with UUIDs, e.g.:

```
/511017a7-67fc-4897-80c1-0d42ac100b68/415.pdf
/511015bc-e0a8-4ab7-ba29-0ce9ac100b68/122.pdf
```

My required result would be:

```
/511017a7-67fc-4897-80c1-0d42ac100b68/415.pdf
/511017a7-67fc-4897-80c1-0d42ac100b68/thumb_415.png
/511015bc-e0a8-4ab7-ba29-0ce9ac100b68/122.pdf
/511015bc-e0a8-4ab7-ba29-0ce9ac100b68/thumb_122.png
```

Any help on the best ways to get this conversion to happen for all *.pdf recursively would be much appreciated!

Comment: Also, a way to do the same with `find`: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61656/omitting-extension-with-find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`find /source/directory -name "*.pdf" -exec \
sh -c 'convert -thumbnail x80 {} $(dirname {})/thumb_$(basename {})' \;`

I had to modify it slightly to:

`find /source/directory -name "*.pdf" -exec \
sh -c 'convert -thumbnail x80 {} $(dirname {})/thumb_$(basename {} .pdf)'.png \;`

To have basename strip the filextension and then append .png.

Thanks to all answers. This one worked well for me!

Comment: I needed to modify it to:

`find /source/directory -name "*.pdf" -exec \ sh -c 'convert -thumbnail x80 {} $(dirname {})/thumb_$(basename {} .pdf)'.png \;`

to have basename strip the fileext. Thanks to all answers this one worked best for me!

Comment: Exercise to the reader: what happens if there's a file called `$(rm -rf /).pdf` somewhere in there.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: Good point.  I had to originally add "sh -c..." to get the filename properly passed to the basename / dirname commands, but that opened up this security hole.  If you are doing this on an untrusted directory, you can replace `{}` with `'\''{}'\''`, however you run into the same issue if a file is named `'$(evil_command)'`.  Not sure of a correct way to close this one.

Answer (score 1):

The tricky part is to not have a filename of the form `testfile.pdf.png` as the output. Years ago I had the same problem and solved it with this helper script (adapted a bit):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash 
SRCFRM=pdf
TGTFRM=png
FILE=$1

NEWFILE=$(echo $FILE | sed "s:$SRCFRM\$:$TGTFRM:")
convert -thumbnail x80 $FILE[0] $NEWFILE
```

Store it somewhere, e.g. in your home dir, then use it like this:

```
find /path -name '*.pdf' -exec /path/to/converthelper.sh {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to

- Recurse into all PDFs:

  1. Enable globstar, with `shopt -s globstar`.
  2. Use it to generate a list of all the `*.pdf` files under the current directory: `**/*.pdf`
  3. Create a loop that iterates over said files:

     ```
     for filename in **/*.pdf
     do
         something
     done
     ```
- Now, you want to do something on the files: something is `convert -thumbnail x80 95.pdf[0] thumb_95.png`. There are several ways: I usually use `basename`, in this case you would need `$(dirname $filename)/$(basename $filename .pdf).png`, but another interesting (and simpler) approach is to use [bash's string manipulation tools](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html):

  1. Remove `.pdf` from the end of the filename: `${filename%.pdf}`
  2. Add `.png`: `${filename%.pdf}.png`

Finally, we can glue it all together (don't forget that this requires globstar, `shopt -s globstar`):

```
for filename in **/*.pdf
do
    convert -thumbnail x80 $filename[0] ${filename%.pdf}.png
done
```